# Collision detection-too fast

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection

I've looked through a few other answers and it seems like I'm doing a dynamic timestep update and I'm checking about 10 pixels before the rectangle to see if it would intersect.
However, the updating must be too fast, because it will register a detection (I checked via print statement debugging) it just wont fire the stop method.

My player update:

```
public void update(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, int deltaTime) {
    gamescreen.xScroll += getSpeedX();
    gamescreen.yScroll += getSpeedY();

    this.xPos += getSpeedX();
    this.yPos += getSpeedY();

    if((gamescreen.getXScroll() + 800) >= (map.w * 64)) gamescreen.xScroll = (map.w * 64 - 800);
    if(this.getXPos() >= (map.w * 64)) this.xPos = (map.w * 64);

    if(gamescreen.getXScroll() <= 0) gamescreen.xScroll = 0;
    if(this.getXPos() <= 0) this.xPos = 0;

    if(gamescreen.getYScroll() <= 0) gamescreen.yScroll = 0;
    if(this.getYPos() > 0) this.yPos = 0;

    if((gamescreen.getYScroll() + 480) >= (map.h * 64)) gamescreen.yScroll = (map.h * 64 - 480);
    if(this.getYPos() >= (map.h * 64)) this.yPos = (map.h * 64);

    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

        if(event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {
            //Right.
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 150, 330, 70, 70) && isMovingLeft() == false && (gamescreen.getXScroll() + 800) < (map.w * 64)) {
                if(gamescreen.checkEntities(map.trees).equals("right")) {
                    stopRight(deltaTime);
                }
                else {
                    moveRight(deltaTime);
                    setMovingRight(true);
                }
            }
            //Left.
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 0, 350, 70, 70) && isMovingRight() == false && gamescreen.getXScroll() > 0) {
                if(gamescreen.checkEntities(map.trees).equals("left")) {
                    stopLeft(deltaTime);
                }
                else {
                    moveLeft(deltaTime);
                    setMovingLeft(true);
                }
            }
            //Up.
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 50, 280, 70, 70) && isMovingDown() == false) {
                if(gamescreen.checkEntities(map.trees).equals("top")) {
                    stopUp(deltaTime);
                }
                else {
                    moveUp(deltaTime);
                    setMovingUp(true);
                }
            }
            //Down.
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 50, 430, 70, 70) && isMovingUp() == false) {
                if(gamescreen.checkEntities(map.trees).equals("bottom")) {
                    stopDown(deltaTime);
                }
                else {
                    moveDown(deltaTime);
                    setMovingDown(true);
                }
            }
        }

        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 150, 330, 80, 80)) {
                setMovingRight(false);
                stop(deltaTime);
            }
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 0, 350, 80, 80)) {
                setMovingLeft(false);
                stop(deltaTime);
            }
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 50, 280, 80, 80)) {
                setMovingUp(false);
                stop(deltaTime);
            }
            if (gamescreen.inBounds(event, 50, 430, 80, 80)) {
                setMovingDown(false);
                stop(deltaTime);
            }           
        }
    }
    gamescreen.checkEntities(map.trees);

    if (playerHealth == 0 || gamescreen.clock.minutes == 5)
    gamescreen.state = GameState.GameOver;
}
```

entity check (kind of a mess):

```
public String checkEntities(BigEntity[] trees) {
    for(int j = 0; j < trees.length; j++) {
        if(player.getRect().right + 10 >= trees[j].getRect().left && player.getRect().bottom >= trees[j].getRect().top && player.getRect().top <= trees[j].getRect().bottom) {
            return "right";
        }
        if(player.getRect().left - 10 <= trees[j].getRect().right && player.getRect().bottom >= trees[j].getRect().top && player.getRect().top <= trees[j].getRect().bottom){
            return "left";
        }
        if(player.getRect().bottom + 10 >= trees[j].getRect().top && player.getRect().right >= trees[j].getRect().left && player.getRect().left <= trees[j].getRect().right) {
            return "bottom";
        }
        if(player.getRect().top - 10 <= trees[j].getRect().bottom && player.getRect().right >= trees[j].getRect().left && player.getRect().left <= trees[j].getRect().right) {
            return "top";
        }
    }
    return "null";
}
```

Comment: This sounds much like a fix my code question. You've told us the problem and presented your code, what kind of answers are you expecting? What's the question? Other than the implied, "What's wrong with my code?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like checkEntities is behaving in an unexpected manner.

The first things I would check are:

- trees has the right data
- the coordinate system has y=0 at the top of the screen

If these are both true then place a breakpoint at the start of the method and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Basically, a print statement will show that a collision has occurred, even if I pass through the object.  I think I pass through the object because my player.update() method doesn't realize there's a collision untill the next iteration (which is why I can slowly move the player to the desired edge and it will stop no matter how many times I try to move).  It basically seems to skip the stop method in player.update().

Comment: What are you doing when a collision is detected? Common strategies are to immediately correct the entities position so there is no overlap and to zero or mirror the velocity (stop or bounce).  If you are using print to debug make sure you are not just marking execution of that code block but also dumping all  key variable to screen.